# Minimum neurons needed to implement any binary function with 1-hidden-layer

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, neural-networks

I am trying to design a 1-hidden-layer neural network to implement parity bit checker for 5-bit length inputs, wherein each neuron has a simple threshold activation i.e.

$$ a(z)=
\begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if  }  z\ge threshold \\
0 & \text{if  }  otherwise \\
\end{cases}
$$
The parity checker should yield 1 for even number of ON bits, and zero otherwise.

The answer, I referred to, has $2^{(5-1)}=16$ neurons for the hidden layer. Whereas, I could design a network (see below) using only 5 neurons for the same layer. **Wondering, what does this $2^{(n-1)}$ signify? Is it the max bound of hidden neurons for a 1-hidden-layer neural network? What is the minimum bound expression, if any?**

*Note: I know the concept behind the $2^{(n-1)}$, as in, how any binary function can be expressed as DNF (disjunctive normal form) of $2^n$ terms, and how they can be simplified to $\frac{2^n}{2}$ terms where each term can be implemented with a single neuron with threshold activation.*

*Note: I also found that my design with $5 (=\log_2{2^{n=5}} \div \log_2{2^{m=1}})$ hidden neurons matches with this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/246931125_Neural_Networks_-_A_Model_of_Boolean_Functions). Is the lowest bound expression from this paper accepted widely!*

[image]